# Find difference between two columns using Hibernate Projections

Tags: hibernate

I have the following query:

```
List results = getSession()
                .createCriteria(AppointmentSlot.class)
                .setProjection(
                        Projections.projectionList()
                                .add(Projections.min("startTime"))
                                .add(Projections.max("endTime"))
                                .add(Projections.groupProperty("clinicInfo"))
                                .add(Projections.groupProperty("staffInfo"))
                                .add(Projections.groupProperty("status"))
                                .add(Projections.groupProperty("dayId")))
                .list();
```

I would like to select additional property which calculates the difference of `min("startTime")` and `max("endTime")`.

**UPDATE**

Sample values in database for both columns `startTime` and `endTime`

1. 08:00:00, 08:15:00
2. 08:15:00, 09:00:00
3. 09:00:00, 09:15:00
   ...

How is this possible using Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sql projection. Something like

```
List results = getSession()
                .createCriteria(AppointmentSlot.class, "apps")
                .setProjection(
                        Projections.projectionList()
                                .add(Projections.min("startTime").as("minStart"))
                                .add(Projections.max("endTime").as("maxTime"))
                                .add(Projections.groupProperty("clinicInfo"))
                                .add(Projections.groupProperty("staffInfo"))
                                .add(Projections.groupProperty("status"))
                                .add(Projections.groupProperty("dayId")))
                                .add(Projections.sqlProjection("(apps.minStart- apps.maxTime) as duration", new String[]{"duration"}, new org.hibernate.type.DateType[]{new org.hibernate.type.DateType()}),"duration")
                .list();
```

Comment: Can I use it within the same query ? Cos I tried it and it gives me `Value '0' can not be represented as java.sql.Date`

Comment: what's the type of `startTime` and `endTime` ?

Comment: It's `org.joda.time.LocalTime`

Comment: try with `TimestampType`

Comment: I still get similar error, `Cannot convert value '0' from column 3 to TIMESTAMP`. Does this mean the `duration` is 0 ?

Comment: @abiieez updated, were you trying something like this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39011/discussion-between-abiieez-and-eugen-halca)